# How to store gettext plural form in a variable using php

Tags: php, gettext

I'm new to PHP. I just started working on it.

I'm trying to get the plural form using `gettext` and PHP. My code is as follows:

```
printf (ngettext ("%d product", "%d products", 2), 2);
```

**Output:**

```
2 products
```

But, I want to have this o/p in a variable. When I try to give it as:

```
$totalItemsCount = printf (ngettext ("%d product", "%d products", 2), 2);
echo "Total count msgs::",$totalItemsCount;
```

**Output:**

```
10
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf()` displays a string, `sprintf()` returns it. However, `printf()` has a return value - it returns the string length. In this case, the resultant string is `2 products`, and the length of this string is `10`.

From the [documentation for `printf()`](http://php.net/printf):

> **Return Values:**
>
> Returns the length of the outputted string.

If you want to store the output in a variable, use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) instead.

```
$totalItemsCount = sprintf (ngettext ("%d product", "%d products", 2), 2);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I need to do translation as well. Its giving output only in English. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Nizam: You're welcome! That's a different question and should be posted as such.