# Not able to translate for plurals using gettext php

Tags: php, gettext

I'm able to translate the text using gettext library. But, when I try to convert the same for plural forms, it gives only in English. I've already mentioned the plural form in my .po files. My code has

```
public $localeFetch;     
public function __construct() {

        require_once(APP_ROOT."/includes/streams.php");
        require_once(APP_ROOT."/includes/gettext.php");            

        $localeLang = $_REQUEST['lang'];  // Take the Language I/p.            
        $localeLangfile = new FileReader(APP_ROOT."/includes/display/locale/$localeLang/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo");            

        $this->localeFetch = new gettext_reader($localeLangfile);
    }

getTranslatedString("Your wish list contains");

public function getTranslatedString($text){
        $returnedString = $this->localeFetch->translate($text);             
        return $returnedString;
}
```

It gives the translated output..

But, for example, if I give

```
printf (ngettext ("%d product", "%d products", 2), 2);   

Output:
----------------
2 products.
```

I want to convert this too in translated plural form.

I'm confused in getting the translated plural form. where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please format your code properly (see how I changed the formatting for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496212/how-to-store-gettext-plural-form-in-a-variable-using-php). Steps: select the code block, press Ctrl + K (or you can click the `{}` button in the editor)

Comment: The PHP locale is set correctly?

Comment: @Axel, Yes. It has set correctly. Because I'm able to translate the text using a function getTranslatedString(parameter). I'm confused how to pass the plural o/p.

Comment: I guess we should have a look at the method behind $this->localeFetch->translate

Comment: translate is the method which is specified in gettext.php